# jQuery/JavaScript runs in console and shows up in source but does not run in joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, virtuemart

This is all in the header of the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/libraries/featuredimagezoomer.js">
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function($){
 $j('.main-image img:first').attr('ID', 'zoom');
 image = $j('.main-image img:first').attr('src');
 console.log(image);

$j('#zoom').addimagezoom({
zoomrange: [3, 10],
magnifiersize: [300,300],
magnifierpos: 'right',
cursorshade: true,
largeimage: image
})  })
</script>
```

It will run from the console just fine, but I have to enter in the external JS file manually, even though it shows up under the "scripts" tab in chrome/webkit. It even shows up in the source, but isn't being run for some reason.

Site is running Joomla 1.7.3 and has the virtuemart plugin.

Comment: What do you mean with "enter in manually"?

Comment: Two things:

 1. `$j(document).ready(function($){` can just be `$j(function($){`
 2. It sounds like you need to do a little diagnostic work.  Could you please try adding (at the start of your script tag) something like console.log("Script was run"), and then inside your onReady function something like console.log("onReady was run")?  I'd be curious to hear if both messages get logged to the console (and in what order).

Comment: I've tried logging to the console before, but I went ahead and ran what you said. Neither message was logged.

Comment: Is it just in the template or really in the source of the generated page? Could you give us a link?

Comment: If neither message is getting logged, that means your code isn't running at all.  You said that the script is there, but can you please check specifically that: A) when you right-click and "view source" the page the script tag really is there, and B) if it is, copy the URL of the script (ie. the "src" attribute), close the view source window, and paste the URL that you copied in to the address bar (if it's a relative URL, ie. it starts with "/", put your domain in front of it).  That *should* take you to view your script, but I'm guessing you'll see a 404 or something instead.

Comment: I've already checked the link the the external JS file; it works. The script tags show up in the source. I'm on my phone right now; I can update with a more in depth response when I get home.

Comment: Ok, this may sound strange but ... that first line is your script tag right?  And that second chunk of code (after the "...") is the contents of your featuredimagezoomer.js file, right?  If so, does that mean you have "<script type="text/javascript">" inside your js file?

Comment: Also, have you checked for errors on the page?  If you use Firebug you can see the errors in the Firebug console.  If you use Firefox you can see them in Tools=>Web Developer=>Error Console.  If you're on Chrome you can see them in the browser's developer tools console, and if you're using any other browser you're using the wrong browser for web development ;-)

Comment: @machineghost I noticed I was missing a </script>, added it in and now  now I'm getting the messages logged to the console.

     `console.log("Script was run")
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function($){
      console.log("On Ready Was Run")
     $j('.main-image img:first').attr('ID', 'zoom');
     image = $j('.main-image img:first').attr('src');
     console.log(image);`

This is what was returned:
     `index.php:93 Script was run
     index.php:96 On Ready Was Run
     index.php:99 undefined`

Comment: Note: line 99 is where it's trying to log the image.
So javascript is now running, but jQuery isnt.

Comment: It looks like everything is working fine, except that $j(".main-image:first").attr('src') is undefined.  I would recommend that you add console.log($j(".main-image:first")) right before (or instead of) the console.log(image).  It seems likely that A) you don't have a .main-image, or B) you do but it's not there at onReady time, or C) you have one there, at onReady time, but it has no src attribute.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The class was being defined by another script, so I had to set a timeout to make sure it didn't try and run until after it was set. Going to look into having it do that on an event.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Congrats on getting it figured out; you're quite welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running JQuery twice because of VirtueMart. **[Turn off](http://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/virtuemart/wiki/General_JS-Problems_with_templates_and_jQuery)** one or the other.

Comment: Would that really break things?  Since the OP used noConflict ("var $j = jQuery.noConflict();") I would think having both would be fine unless VirtueMart also uses "$j".  But I don't know VirtueMart nor have I ever tested this, so I'm just asking (not saying the answer is wrong).

Comment: I tried disabling it and it didn't work. It broke the cart and didn't detect jQuery at all anymore; so I added it to the head through the google API and is still did not work.

Another plugin that the site uses that could possibly be conflicting with it is gallerific.

Answer (score 0):

So, in essence I wound up answering this question in the comments.  Just to summarize for posterity, the final solution was basically: "apply debugging strategies like using console.log to check your assumptions and figure out what's going wrong".  If you have a problem similar to this question's you *might* want to read the comments, but the particulars of it were pretty isolated to thebeefytaco's specific case.